# Error correction software for VASP calculations

Tags: vasp, software-recommendations, one-topic-per-answer, high-throughput

I am looking for error correction packages for VASP calculations that can be integrated into a high-throughput worfklow. Ideally the software would both find and propose fixes for errors at runtime, but just reporting errors during post-processing would be okay as well. I sometimes run one-off calculations that also need to be checked.

The only comprehensive error corrector that I know about is [Custodian](https://github.com/materialsproject/custodian/blob/master/custodian/vasp/handlers.py) from the Materials Project. I've looked briefly at other frameworks such as ASE and pyiron and did not find anything comparable, but it may be because I am not as familiar with them.